# How to create rule that returns each value as unique

Tags: prolog, crossword, prolog-dif

I'm following along with [Learn Prolog Now!](http://www.learnprolognow.org/) and was looking at [Exercise 2.4](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse7).

A solution I [found here](https://github.com/lorenzo-stoakes/learn-prolog-now/blob/master/exercises/02.md) seems to solve, but not completely:

```
word(astante,  a,s,t,a,n,t,e). 
word(astoria,  a,s,t,o,r,i,a). 
word(baratto,  b,a,r,a,t,t,o). 
word(cobalto,  c,o,b,a,l,t,o). 
word(pistola,  p,i,s,t,o,l,a). 
word(statale,  s,t,a,t,a,l,e).

crossword(V1,V2,V3,H1,H2,H3) :- 
  word(V1, _, V1H1, _, V1H2, _, V1H3, _),
  word(V2, _, V2H1, _, V2H2, _, V2H3, _),
  word(V3, _, V3H1, _, V3H2, _, V3H3, _),
  word(H1, _, V1H1, _, V2H1, _, V3H1, _),
  word(H2, _, V1H2, _, V2H2, _, V3H2, _),
  word(H3, _, V1H3, _, V2H3, _, V3H3, _).
```

This produces the following results:

```
H1 = astoria
H2 = baratto
H3 = statale
V1 = astante
V2 = cobalto
V3 = pistola ? ;

H1 = astante
H2 = cobalto
H3 = pistola
V1 = astoria
V2 = baratto
V3 = statale ? ;

H1 = astoria
H2 = cobalto
H3 = pistola
V1 = astoria
V2 = cobalto
V3 = pistola ? ;

H1 = baratto
H2 = baratto
H3 = statale
V1 = baratto
V2 = baratto
V3 = statale ? ;

H1 = cobalto
H2 = baratto
H3 = statale
V1 = cobalto
V2 = baratto
V3 = statale ? ;

H1 = astante
H2 = baratto
H3 = statale
V1 = astante
V2 = baratto
V3 = statale ? ;
```

Of these, only 2 are practical:

```
H1 = astoria
H2 = baratto
H3 = statale
V1 = astante
V2 = cobalto
V3 = pistola ? ;

H1 = astante
H2 = cobalto
H3 = pistola
V1 = astoria
V2 = baratto
V3 = statale ? ;
```

Because the other 3 solutions contain duplicates, they are not viable answers for the problem.

How can I add to the crossword rule to have it only return results where V1,V2,V3,H1,H2,H3 are all unique?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a procedure like this to ensure values are all different:

```
all_dif([]).
all_dif([A|Tail]):-
  all_dif(Tail, A),
  all_dif(Tail).

all_dif([], _).
all_dif([B|Tail], A):-
  dif(A,B),
  all_dif(Tail, A).
```

and call it with `all_dif([V1,V2,V3,H1,H2,H3])`

Answer (score 1):

a common technique make use of [select/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=select/3), to get unique alternative elements on backtracking:

```
crossword(V1,V2,V3,H1,H2,H3) :-
    selects(
        [[V1, _, V1H1, _, V1H2, _, V1H3, _],
         [V2, _, V2H1, _, V2H2, _, V2H3, _],
         [V3, _, V3H1, _, V3H2, _, V3H3, _],
         [H1, _, V1H1, _, V2H1, _, V3H1, _],
         [H2, _, V1H2, _, V2H2, _, V3H2, _],
         [H3, _, V1H3, _, V2H3, _, V3H3, _]
        ],
        [[a,s,t,a,n,t,e],
         [a,s,t,o,r,i,a],
         [b,a,r,a,t,t,o],
         [c,o,b,a,l,t,o],
         [p,i,s,t,o,l,a],
         [s,t,a,t,a,l,e]
        ]).

selects([], []).
selects([[W|Cs]|Ws], L) :-
    select(Cs, L, R),
    selects(Ws, R),
    atom_chars(W, Cs).
```

This is clearly an alternative method to the very simple solution you already found.

select/3 can also be used to check that there are no duplicates in list:

```
crossword(V1,V2,V3,H1,H2,H3) :-
  word(V1, _, V1H1, _, V1H2, _, V1H3, _),
  word(V2, _, V2H1, _, V2H2, _, V2H3, _),
  word(V3, _, V3H1, _, V3H2, _, V3H3, _),
  word(H1, _, V1H1, _, V2H1, _, V3H1, _),
  word(H2, _, V1H2, _, V2H2, _, V3H2, _),
  word(H3, _, V1H3, _, V2H3, _, V3H3, _),
  maplist(nodup([V1,V2,V3,H1,H2,H3]), [V1,V2,V3,H1,H2,H3]).

nodup(L, E) :- select(E, L, R), \+ memberchk(E, R).
```

At last, since sort/2 removes duplicates, the easiest check could be

```
crossword(V1,V2,V3,H1,H2,H3) :-
  word(V1, _, V1H1, _, V1H2, _, V1H3, _),
  word(V2, _, V2H1, _, V2H2, _, V2H3, _),
  word(V3, _, V3H1, _, V3H2, _, V3H3, _),
  word(H1, _, V1H1, _, V2H1, _, V3H1, _),
  word(H2, _, V1H2, _, V2H2, _, V3H2, _),
  word(H3, _, V1H3, _, V2H3, _, V3H3, _),
  sort([V1,V2,V3,H1,H2,H3], [_,_,_,_,_,_]).
```